# Update operation in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Here is a question raised during our data structure design. Currently, we have a data as the following:

```
class {
  private String id;
  private Map<String, Object> map;
  ...
}
```

We will have an operation to add new entries to the map frequently. I am wondering whether the data needs to be fetched from DynamoDB first, add new entries to the map and do a DB update with the modified data or not? (That is how Mongo update works.) If not, the data structure design isn't good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to fetch the data from DynamoDB first and then add a new entry to map and save the object.

If the object is of type List, then you can append values to the existing list.

```
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
nameList.add("1");
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("Id", testId).withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW).withUpdateExpression("set #Names = list_append (#Names, :val1)").withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#Names", "Names"))
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withList(":val1", nameList));
UpdateItemOutcome outcome = table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. We need to redesign the data structure.